# com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch not calling OnClickListener first Click

Tags: android

I am trying to get the Switch (from https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) to register the first toggle. The situation is that when i first start up the app, and toggle the Switch from OFF to ON, rather than turning the screen to greyscale, nothing happens. I believe this is due to the line of code `materialdesign:check="true"` , where the app thinks that the Switch is already turned on so there is no state change. However, if I have the the screen already in greyscale, the first toggle from ON to OFF does register. The toggles after that work perfectly fine.

I'm really confused as to why this is happening.

> activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Toggle monochrome" />

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch
        android:id="@+id/monochromeSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1E88E5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        materialdesign:check="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
    private void initMonochromeSwitch(final Switch monochromeSwitch) {
    if (Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), ACCESSIBILITY_DISPLAY_DALTONIZER_ENABLED, 0) == 0) {
        monochromeSwitch.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        monochromeSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }

    monochromeSwitch.setOncheckListener(new Switch.OnCheckListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onCheck(Switch view, boolean check) {
            //Checks if this app can modify system settings
            boolean canWriteSettings = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            if (canWriteSettings) {
                if (check) {
                    toggleMonochrome(1, getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());
                } else {
                    toggleMonochrome(0, getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());
                }
            } else {
                //If currently cant modify system settings, app will ask for permission
                showRootWorkaroundInstructions(getApplicationContext());
                monochromeSwitch.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void toggleMonochrome(int value, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, ACCESSIBILITY_DISPLAY_DALTONIZER_ENABLED, value);
    if (value == 0) {
        Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, ACCESSIBILITY_DISPLAY_DALTONIZER, -1);
    } else if (value == 1) {
        Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, ACCESSIBILITY_DISPLAY_DALTONIZER, 0);
    }
}
```

> LogCat

First Toggle - Nothing happens

```
03-12 14:30:50.882 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler D/ViewRootImpl@cc84c90[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-12 14:30:50.884 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
03-12 14:30:50.886 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
03-12 14:30:50.886 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
03-12 14:30:51.099 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler D/ViewRootImpl@cc84c90[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

2nd Toggle - Correctly Switches back to colour (I tested it by using toasts in onClick Listener)

```
03-12 14:31:40.754 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler D/ViewRootImpl@cc84c90[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-12 14:31:40.903 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler D/ViewRootImpl@cc84c90[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

3rd Toggle - Correctly Changes to greyScale

```
03-12 14:32:00.242 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler D/ViewRootImpl@cc84c90[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-12 14:32:00.491 32598-32598/com.example.jeremy.monochrometoggler D/ViewRootImpl@cc84c90[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```